# Sorting an object by its value using lodash

Tags: angularjs, sorting, object, lodash

I’m trying to sort an object alphabetically by its value using loadash only. My sample object is

```
 var object =  {AB:'apple',AC:'cat', AD:'bannana', BA:'atom'};
```

And i’m trying to get output as follows:

```
Object  = {AB: "apple", BA: "atom", AD: "bannana", AC: "cat"}
```

I tried using _.sortBy, but it doesn’t seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as sorting the properties of an object. An object is just an unordered set of key <-> property pairs.

You can create an array with the values of the object and sort them.

As explained in the lodash [sortBy documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy), the sortBy method create a sorted array (ie. an ordered list) from the values of a collection.
I am not sure that it fits your need. See the following snippet, that use your object as input value.

```js
var object =  {AB:'apple',AC:'cat', AD:'bannana', BA:'atom'};
var sortedValues = _.sortBy(object, function(value) { return value; });
console.log(sortedValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:
From your comment, you need to get the (key, value) pairs to iterate over a list of pairs.
Here is a proposed solution with a sorted array that is used in a `ng-repeat` directive.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {

    var object = {
      AB: 'apple',
      AC: 'cat',
      AD: 'bannana',
      BA: 'atom'
    };

    var pairs = _.map(object, function(value, key) {
      return [key, value];
    });

    $scope.sortedPairs = _.sortBy(pairs, function(pair) {
      return pair[1]; // ie. value
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="pair in sortedPairs">
      key: {{pair[0]}}, value: {{pair[1]}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Then how can i get the keys to it, i need to use those key, value pairs to ng-repeat in html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may be i can convert this array to a key value pair,  So then i can get my answer.

Comment: you can iterate directly from the sortedPairs array using ng-repeat with something like `<ul><li ng-repeat="pair in sortedPairs">key: {{pair[0]}}, value: {{pair[1]}}</li></ul>`

Comment: i edited the snippet in my answer with an ng-repeat directive.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks bud :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort objects, but you can convert it to array of pairs and sortBy then:

```js
const sorted = _.sortBy(_.toPairs(object), 1)
```

now you have ordered array:

```js
[
  ["AB", "apple"], 
  ["BA", "atom"], 
  ["AD", "bannana"], 
  ["AC", "cat"]
]
```